# calculate the time elapsed since the last occurrence of the same type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame

```
                dtm  cultivation-table irrigation fertilizer
2022-01-09 10:30:40                  1        NaN        Yes 
2022-01-09 10:31:20                  1        NaN        Yes
2022-01-09 10:34:12                  1        0.5        Yes 
2022-01-09 10:40:18                  1        NaN        NaN
2022-01-09 10:41:20                  1        NaN        NaN
2022-01-09 10:32:54                  2        NaN        NaN 
2022-01-09 10:35:08                  2        NaN        Yes
2022-01-09 10:31:10                  3        NaN        Yes
2022-01-09 10:32:23                  3          1        NaN
```

That Dataframe can have one or more columns of an array (`activities = ['irrigation', 'fertilizer', 'prune', 'insecticide']`)
I need to add a new column for each activity that puts the time elapsed since the activity was last performed on each grow table.

This is the expected result

```
                dtm  cultivation-table irrigation   time_irrigation fertilizer time_fertilizer 
2022-01-09 10:30:40                  1        NaN      00:00:00          Yes       00:00:00
2022-01-09 10:31:20                  1        NaN      00:00:40          Yes       00:00:40
2022-01-09 10:34:12                  1        0.5      00:03:32          Yes       00:02:52
2022-01-09 10:40:18                  1        NaN      00:06:06          NaN       00:08:58
2022-01-09 10:41:20                  1        NaN      00:07:08          NaN       00:10:00
2022-01-09 10:32:54                  2        NaN      00:00:00          NaN       00:00:00
2022-01-09 10:35:08                  2        NaN      00:02:14          Yes       00:02:14
2022-01-09 10:31:10                  3        NaN      00:00:00          Yes       00:00:00
2022-01-09 10:32:23                  3          1      00:01:13          NaN       00:01:13
```

How could I do this?

Comment: group on `cultivation-table` then use [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) on the `dtm` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok think I finally have it. The trick was to consider whether each row was the first one in it's `cultivation-table` as well as whether or not it was null

This approach uses `pd.where` to find the last time an activity took place and `ffill`s and `shifts` per `cultivation-table`. The last times then subtracted from the `dtm` column

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
dtm,cultivation-table,irrigation,fertilizer
2022-01-09 10:30:40,1,,Yes
2022-01-09 10:31:20,1,,Yes
2022-01-09 10:34:12,1,0.5,
2022-01-09 10:40:18,1,,
2022-01-09 10:41:20,1,,
2022-01-09 10:32:54,2,,
2022-01-09 10:35:08,2,,Yes
2022-01-09 10:31:10,3,,Yes
2022-01-09 10:32:23,3,1,
"""),parse_dates=['dtm'])

activities = ['irrigation', 'fertilizer', 'prune', 'insecticide']

first_in_table = df['cultivation-table'].diff().fillna(1)

for activity in activities:
    #find the column number of the activity so we know where to insert the new column
    #if it's not found then skip that activity
    c_pos = None
    for i,c in enumerate(df.columns):
        if c == activity:
            c_pos = i
            break

    if not c_pos:
        continue
        
        
    #last active times per cultivation-table
    last_activity = df['dtm'].where(
        df[activity].notnull() | first_in_table
    ).groupby(
        df['cultivation-table']
    ).transform(lambda v: v.ffill().shift())
    
    #subtracting the last active time from the dtm
    td = df['dtm'].subtract(last_activity).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
    
    #inserting the new column
    c_name = f'time_{activity}'
    df.insert(i+1,c_name,td)
```

Our outputs differ in the time_fertilizer column because I think when you edited your output to add the 3rd "yes" you didn't update the times
[image]